# setInterval with changing parameters for function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I would like to periodically call a function (assume it's name is "alter(id)") with the parameter changing every call. The parameter should increment with every call and return to 0 at some point. On a timeline it would look like this:

```
Time: function to call
0ms: alter(0)
300ms: alter(1)
600ms: alter(2)
900ms: alter(3)
1200ms: alter(0)
1500ms: alter(1)
and so on ad infinitum.
```

Comment: @Chris: I am aware of this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function but don't know how to adapt it to a case where the parameter should change every call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    let counter = 0; // closure
    const INTERVAL = 300;// 300ms
    const alter = (arg) => { /* alter function body */ }
    const tick = () => {
      counter = alter(counter);
      counter = a < 3 ? a + 1: 0;
    }   
    tick(); // 0ms
    setInterval(tick, INTERVAL); // call each 300 ms
```

[setInterval documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I change my answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Some explanation of the code would improve this answer