# Javascript setinterval function with arguments

Tags: javascript

How do I pass arguments in the setInterval function
Eg:

```
 intId = setInterval(waiting(argument), 10000);
```

It shows error `: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)`

Comment: setInterval(function(){waiting(argument)}, 10000)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass parameters in setInterval function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use an anonymous function

```
 intId = setInterval(function(){waiting(argument)}, 10000);
```

This creates a parameterless anonymous function which calls `waiting()` with arguments

Or use the optional parameters of the `setInterval()` function:

```
 intId = setInterval(waiting, 10000, argument [,...more arguments]);
```

Your code ( `intId = setInterval(waiting(argument), 10000);`) calls `waiting()` with `argument`, takes the return value, tries to treat it as a function, and sets the interval for that return value. Unless `waiting()` is a function which returns another function, this will fail, as you can only treat functions as functions. Numbers/strings/objects can't be typecast to a function.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
intId = setInterval(waiting.bind(window, argument), 10000);
```

It returns a function that will call the target function with the given context (`window`) and any optional arguments.

Answer (score 7):

Use this method:

```
 var interval = setInterval( callback , 500 , arg1 , arg2[, argn ] );
 [...]
 function callback(arg1, arg2[, etc]){
 }
```

More info here: [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bind and apply functions to store the argument in state.

Example using bind in node shell:

```
> var f = function(arg) { console.log (arg);}
> f()
undefined
> f("yo")
yo
> var newarg = "stuff";
> f(newarg)
stuff
> var fn = f.bind(this, newarg);
> fn()
stuff
> var temp = setTimeout(fn,1000)
> stuff
```

Answer (score -3):

setInterval( function() { funca(10,3); }, 500 );

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457826/4642212) is the question you were trying to answer.