# Ajax requests seems to not respect the timer

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to keep polling a server for informations, so I set this recursive function:

```
function getStats(){ 
 $.getJSON("Stats", function(statList){
            //parse the statList and update page's html

            setTimeout(getStats(), 5000);//recalling
 });
}
```

Looking at wireshark I see that the frequency is NOT every 5 seconds like it should!
How come?

And while we are at it...this function is executed in a jquery tab, I'd like that when I change tab it just stops sending requests..how to do this too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use repeatedly, you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

```
setInterval(function () {
$.getJSON("Stats", function (statList) {
    //parse the statList and update page's html


});
}, 3000);
```

setTimeout(); will execute only once. Also there is a problem with your calling of `setTimeout`, ie dont need to use `()` in specifying the method. Your call should look like

```
setTimeout(getStats, 5000);
```

**Edit**

```
 function getStats() {
  $.getJSON("Stats", function (statList) {
       //parse the statList and update page's html

  });
}
getStats();
setInterval(getStats, 5000);
```

Comment: Problem is that this way first execution takes 5 seconds too, while I'd like for it to be executed instantly

Comment: Another thing...and if I wanted to pass a paramether to my function?

Comment: take a look at these solutions. It definitely will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
setTimeout(getStats(), 5000);
```

`getStats()` is a function so you don't need to apply `()`.

You are using as a callback function of this method so it has to be like:

```
setTimeout(getStats, 5000);
```

---

see this:

```
setTimeout(fn, time_in_ms);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
  // here you can call your function
}, time_in_ms);
```