# setInterval doesn't seem to like () in the function it invokes. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

When I execute the following, `incidentController` gets called after `10` seconds and continues to execute with no problems every `10` seconds:

```
// This works fine in nodejs v0.11.13
setInterval(incidentController, 10 * 1000);

function incidentController () {
 console.log ('executed'); 
}
```

However, this executes **immediately** and throws the following error on the second iteration:

```
//This doesn't. The parens which wrap (123) cause the error.

setInterval(incidentController(123), 10 * 1000);

function incidentController (someInt) {
 console.log ('executed: ', someInt); 
}
```

Error:

```
timers.js:287
    callback.apply(this, args);
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at wrapper [as _onTimeout] (timers.js:287:13)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:133:15)
```

It seems like `incidentController` is/becomes `undefined` somehow. Can someone explain why this is expected behavior (I assume it is, anyway)?

I can work around this pretty easily, but I'm just curious why it behaves this way -- makes passing in parameter values a bit less convenient since I can't do it inside the `setInterval` statement itself.

Comment: because you are executing the function! :) It has no clue you want to assign a reference to it.

Comment: [Pass parameters in setInterval function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function) / [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setInterval` accepts a function object as the first parameter. But, when you do

```
setInterval(incidentController(123), 10 * 1000);
```

you are passing the result of invoking `incidentController`, which is `undefined` (In JavaScript, if a function doesn't return anything explicitly, then by default, `undefined` will be returned). That is why you are getting the error

```
Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

It is trying to invoke the `apply` function on `undefined`.

---

> makes passing in parameter values a bit less convenient since I can't do it inside the `setInterval` statement itself

No, sir. You can conveniently pass the parameter to the callback function in `setInterval` itself, like this

```
setInterval(incidentController, 10 * 1000, 123);
```

Now, when `incidentController` is invoked, after every 10 seconds, `123` will be passed as the first parameter to it.

Comment: did not know that syntax setInterval(incidentController, 10 * 1000, 123);. Is it documented ?

Comment: @maboiteaspam Yup, its documented in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Syntax), and also in [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg)

Comment: Whoa, didn't know about that either, that's cool. I guess that's a recent feature? At the bottom it says IE10+ for callback parameters support.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett Most browsers don't support that yet. But OP has tagged node.js. So, it would work very well for him :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect to use `setInterval` like

```
setInterval(incidentController(123), 10 * 1000);
```

because it expects a function as the first parameter(not an executed function with a result).

If you wish to pass a parameter to the call back, you should wrap the function call with an anonymous function like

```
setInterval(function(){incidentController(123)}, 10 * 1000);
```

See [Pass parameters in setInterval function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function)