# Get image download result

Tags: javascript

If I simplify my javascript code it is like this:

I have object which has method "dwnImage" responsible to download image from some url. When I call this method I would like that result of this method tell me if image was downloaded successfully or there were some error, like img doesn't exists, wrong url. How can I do that?

```
GM.Log=function(){
  var imgLg=null;
  var result=0;
  var imgLoaded = function () {
    result=1;
  };
  var init = function () {
    imgLg= new Image(1,1);
    imgLg.addEventListener('load', imgLoaded(), false);
  }

  var dwnImage=function(url){
    imgLg.src=url;
    return result;
  }
  return {
    init: init
  }
}

var test=new GM.Log();
test.init();
var result=test.dwnImage("http://...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can't. The use of `http://` on the final line of your code implies that you are going to bounce off [the same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy): You can't get load events on cross-origin resources.

---

If that isn't the case then you need to:

1. [Pass a function and not the return value of that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419698/setinterval-doesnt-seem-to-like-in-the-function-it-invokes-why) to `addEventListener`
2. [Learn how to handle asynchronous functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "Pass a function and not the return value"- i don't know what exactly do you mean since I pass a function. Can you correct this sample code to show what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: @Simon — There's a link to a question which details that specific problem. Click it.

Comment: Example is clear to me.But if i add this: imgLg.addEventListener('load', imgLoaded, false); imgLoaded function is never executed(I put alert inside to test). Do you know why?

Comment: @Simon — Probably for the reasons I described in the first paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Ok, if img doesn't exists or is other origin how can I catch result as 0 and when everything ok, the result should be 1.
https://codepen.io/simon1/pen/MbmXpW