# Why JS setInterval does not repeatedly calls a function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

In code below, `setInterval` does not work as you would expect i.e to call `function greet` after every `3s`. It calls `greet` the first time and that too before `3s`.

```
name = "Superman";

function greet(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

setInterval(greet(name), 3000);
```

Can any body tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thanks
bt

Comment: @Quentin shouldn't be duplicate of  **[Pass parameters in setInterval function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457826/pass-parameters-in-setinterval-function)** ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki — That's also a valid duplicate, although I think the one I found was better.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `setInterval` needs to be a function.

You are calling `greet` **immediately** and passing its return value (`undefined` since there is no `return` statement) to `setInterval`.

If you want to call `greet` with arguments on an interval, create a new function which does that and pass *that* function.

```js
var name = "Superman"; // Added `var` here. Implicit globals are problematic and banned in strict mode.

function greet(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

function greetName() {
  greet(name);
}

setInterval(greetName, 3000);
```

Comment: Your first line can be requoted as >The first argument of setInterval needs to be a function **definition**. 
Is that correct?

Comment: @bTech — Not really. A function definition is the JavaScript source code used to create a function. It's the output of that code which needs to be passed.

Comment: I don't fully understand. In the code above, if you pass `greetName` (which is just a reference) you are actually passing `function greetName() {  greet(name); }` the definition to `setInterval`. Also as per [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), > `The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).` So actually `setInterval` does the calling (or execution) for which it needs the reference to the callback's definition.  Pls correct me if I am wrong (perhaps with an example) as I need to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the variable in a global way, like your example. You do not need to have a parameter in the function. Then you could just do this:

```js
name = "Superman";

function greet() {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

setInterval(greet, 3000);
```

But, if you still want to have a parameter, you could do this:

```js
name = "Superman";

function greet(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

setInterval(function () {
  greet(name);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
name = "Superman";

function greet(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

setInterval(function() { return greet(name) }, 3000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add anonymous function `function(){}` to the call of function inside `setInterval()` since you pass parameters to it :

```
name = "Superman";

function greet(name) {
  alert("Hello " + name)
}

setInterval(function() { greet(name) }, 3000);
```

Or just pass parameters as arguments at the end, like :

```
setInterval(greet, 3000, name);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
name = "Superman";

function greet(name) {
  console.log("Hello " + name)
}

//setInterval(function() { greet(name) }, 1000);
//Or
setInterval(greet, 1000, name);
```