# Javascript setInterval(); does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to make a script that changes the header's color every second,
I have made a function that styles a HTML element with a random color whenever it's called, and when I use the setInterval(); it does not work!

```
function randomColor(elementId) {
var colors = ["red","green","blue","purple","lightblue","cyan","yellow","brown","pink","grey"];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById(elementId).style.color = colors[randomNumber];
}

setInterval(randomColor("Header"), 1000);
```

Can someone help? thanks!

Note:
When I refresh the page it only changes the color once.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/457826/256305

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are calling `randomColor` and the result to that function is being passed into `setInterval`.

You should be able to pass a wrapped version in just fine:

```
setInterval(function() { randomColor("Header"); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setInterval` function takes as input a function.  In your example, you are executing `randomColor("Header")` and sending the result to the `setTimer` function.

```
setInterval(function() { randomColor("Header") }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send a function as arugment in setInterval, like this:

```
setInterval(function(){randomColor("Header")}, 1000);
```